# Can port forwarding still work if my router doesn't get a public external IP?

Tags: port-forwarding

This may sound a pretty noobish question and I am pretty sure that I want to do is not possible. But only to make sure, I wanna ask this question.

I was trying hard to forward port UDP 16000 to my local computer from my local router. It was not working even when I did exactly as stated in documentation.

Later I realized that my router doesn't get the public IP directly. Its gets some IP like 168.120.x.x which is not clearly a public IP. I am trying this for Age of empires II only game play. So the situation seems like my local router is connected to other router which is at ISP. And my public IP is at ISP router itself. I contacted ISP if its possible to forward port 16000 to my router, but they refused to do so because we are provided with dynamic pool of IPs.

Can anything by done without bothering ISP or its not possible. Is it possible that I am doing something wrong?

Thank you all..

Comment: you should be able to log into your isp router try the isp rputer ip in th address bar

Comment: I typed the gateway IP of WAN status from my router. It does nothing. so I think this doesn't help.

Comment: The Address Allocation for Private Internets as laid out in RFC 1918 reserve these addresses (per IANA) for private use:  10.0.0.0-10.255.255.255, 172.16.0.0-172.31.255.255 and 192.168.0.0-192.168.255.255. So clearly, 168.x.x.x is a public ip address.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it sounds like your ISP uses NAT to conserve IP addresses.  So your "internet" facing address is in a private range, then gets translated to a public address as it enters the internet.

You won't be able to use portforwarding on your router, unless your ISP cooperates.  Often in this type of situation, letting your ISP know that you need to port forward will result in you receiving a public IP.  So it is worth opening a ticket.

If not, then your next option is to use a VPN service that includes port forwarding.  This will introduce overhead to the connection so isn't usually suitable for applications where latency is important.

Another alternative is to change ISPs.